# Discord.js changes only one voice channel name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have it set that if action A is undertaken or Action B is undertaken, the name of two voice channels are changed:

```
if(A) {
  client.channels.cache.get("871368210727964723").setName(UserInputA);
  client.channels.cache.get("871368209742311445").setName(StoredInputB);
} else {
  client.channels.cache.get("871368210727964723").setName(UserInputA);
  client.channels.cache.get("871368209742311445").setName(StoredInputB_1);
}
```

But for some reason when this action is triggered, Discord.js just completely acts weird. It either changes one voice channel name (usually the first one), the two of them (which is what I want), or changes nothing at all and I have completely no clue as to what could be the issue. I tried setting them into `vars` and then once the action is triggered I tried to add  this towards the end of the code hoping it would help, but still no luck whatsoever:

```
    UserInputA = undefined;
    StoredInputB = undefined;
    StoredInputB_1 = undefined;
    delete(UserInputA);
    delete(StoredInputB);
    delete(StoredInputB_1);
```

And even sometimes on very rare occurrences, it would change after 5 - 10 mins. I even tried making a try/catch statement beforehand to see if maybe an error occurs but nothing is displayed on the console with or without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to rate limiting. The official accepted rate to change a channel name, topic or delet it, is set to **Two Updates per 10 minutes** as stated [here](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/715995470048264233) by Mason on the *Discord Developers* Server.

Discord.js keeps you safe from reching those limits. So if you try to run this code often, discord.js will prevent your bot from being rate limited.

So just be patient, your code looks perfectly good to me. The name changes will occur, they just take time.

[sterlus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15257378/) already talked about this in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66310644/10926046)